# Javascript - execute document call AFTER a function has completed

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd want to do, in my case, the call `document.getElementById` only after a previous function has completed, but it happens the opposite: it first (or at the same time) execute the document call, then the function.
In my specific case, I have a rocket and a counter: the rocket image has to change after the execution of the `contatore()` function.

Here is my function:

```
function rocketLaunch(){
  contatore(10);
  document.getElementById("imgRazzo").src = imgRazzoAcceso.src;
}
```

And here is `contatore` function, that uses `setTimeout`:

```
function contatore(number){

/* if 0, we have to stop the counter and return to the caller */
if(number == 0){
    return;
}else{

    /* js recursive: wait 1 second, than re-call this function with number-1 as parameter*/
    setTimeout(function(){contatore(number - 1)}, 1000);

    /* you can finally inner the html */
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = number;
}
}
```

Comment: is your function `contatore` is related to timeout or interval ??

Comment: i add it, wait a moment. Btw, yes.

Comment: Why not use a callback if it's async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a callback, like this:

```js
// dummy image, just for this demo:
var imgRazzoAcceso = {
    src: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/03/11/58/rocket-312767_1280.png'
};

function rocketLaunch(){
  contatore(10, function () { // callback
    document.getElementById("imgRazzo").src = imgRazzoAcceso.src;
  });
}

function contatore(number, done){
    document.getElementById("main").textContent = number;
    if(number) {
        // use bind for shorter syntax. Also a bit shorter delay for this demo :-)
        setTimeout(contatore.bind(null, number - 1, done), 200);
    } else {
        // when all is done: call callback
        done();
    }
}

rocketLaunch();
```

```css
body { font-size: 50px; text-align: center;  }
```

```html
<img id="imgRazzo" src="https://openclipart.org/download/261322/rocket-297573.svg" width="100px" height="100px"></img>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `await`

```
function rocketLaunch(){
  await contatore();
  document.getElementById("imgRazzo").src = imgRazzoAcceso.src;
}
```

**Demo on how it works**

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function demo() {
  console.log('Taking a break...');
  await sleep(2000);
  console.log('Two second later');
}

demo();
```

Syntax of `sleep` is taken from [this](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-sleep-function) link

Comment: but if condition won't be true and src won't changed. so instead use `while`

Comment: this doesn't make sense.
the next line will execute whether contadore() returns a truthy value or not...

Comment: fiddle is broken :( . is it ecmascript 6 syntax ? promise and await ??

Comment: nice - but as much as I like async functions/await, it's a very new specification and less modern browsers don't support it :(

Comment: Syntax of `sleep` is taken from [this](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-sleep-function) link. which browser u are using?

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have some timeout/interval/ajax call in your function. That's why it's asynchronous. You need to declare callback, pass it as argument and call in `contatore();` when it finished.
Example:

```
var contatore = function(callback) {
   //do stuff here
   callback();
}

var afterFinishedFunction = function(){
  // this will execute when contatore finishes
}

// make it together
contatore(afterFinishedFunction); // (note, there is no brackets like this afterFinishedFunction()
```

Comment: @mitch i just edited the code, removing the customizations and making it simplier. i just try your advice now.

Comment: @mitch why `callback()` won't be called ? if `//do stuff here` have settimeout function

Comment: `callback()` must be called at the end of `setTimeout` body function. You pass only the pointer to function as argument.

Comment: suppose `//do stuff here` have settimeout of 10 sec. then `callback();` will be called within 10 sec right ?

Comment: You need to put `callback();` at the end of `setTimeout(function(){
//do stuff here
callback()
},10000);`

Comment: You need to call callback inside `contatore` function at the end of `setTimeout`

Comment: And not after but inside `setTimeout`

Comment: thank you. right solution but I didn't understand. I found the way with @trincot example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise` constructor, pass `onFulfilled` function reference to a function which calls `setTimeout`; if `number` is equal to `0` call `onFulfilled` to resolve the `Promise`, else recursively call `setTimeout` until `number` is equal to `0`

```js
var imgRazzoAcceso = {
  src: "http://placehold.it/100x100"
}

function rocketLaunch() {
  contatore(10)
  .then(function() {
    document.getElementById("imgRazzo").src = imgRazzoAcceso.src;
  })
}

function checkNumber(n) {
  return n == 0
}

function delay(number, resolve) {
  console.log("delay", number);
  setTimeout(function re() {
    if (checkNumber(number - 1)) {
      resolve()
    } else {
      delay(number - 1, resolve)
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function contatore(number) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    if (checkNumber(number)) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      delay(number - 1, resolve)
    }
  })
}

rocketLaunch()
```

```html
<img id="imgRazzo" alt="imgRazzo" />
```